# How to connect a private subnet to internet without NAT nor EIP in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

In our current VPC we are using and ASG and ALB. We have some public subnets and some private subnets. We would like to be able to connect from time to time, those private subnets to pull some patches out of the internet.

Is my understand that the NAT Gateway requires an EIP. The EIP does not seem to be able to play with the ASG, since it spect an instance/IP. Not sure if the ASG is able to link an EC2 ( can be terminated ) to the EIP.

What changes shall I make to allow those private subnets to access internet, considering my constrains?

Changing the ALB for an ELB is not an option!

Comment: "guys do not like EIP nor NAT" - what does it mean? Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details.

Comment: @Marcin I add more context to my original post! Feel free to let me know, if you need any specifics!

Comment: Your question is a little confusing... Are you saying that the private instances do not currently have Internet access because there is not NAT Gateway/NAT Instance? Are you wanting to use a NAT Gateway? The NAT Gateway would not interfere with an Auto Scaling group or Load Balancer -- what specific problem are you experiencing when you say "The EIP does not seem to be able to play with the ASG"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The **Auto Scaling group** is responsible for launching and terminate Amazon EC2 instances. It will also update the Load Balancer's Target Group with any new/removed instances.

A **NAT Gateway** is used to provide Internet access to resources in Private Subnets. An **Elastic IP address** is assigned to the NAT Gateway and all requests coming through the NAT Gateway will come from that IP address. The NAT Gateway and Elastic IP address are not used with the Load Balancer or Auto Scaling group -- they are totally independent. All EC2 instances in the Private Subnets will only use their normal Private IP addresses.

Comment: the EIP requires to know the IP of the public instance isnt'? is the ASG able to pass that information to the EIP incase terminate the EC2 instance link to the EIP?  Seems  like the issue here is that I need to have at least an EC2 instance that is not link to the ASG. Currently the ASG populates all the subnets private and public

Comment: @Khimaira - I think there may be a language issue here. What John is saying is that an Auto Scaling Group (ASG) is completely independent from a NAT Gateway. No instance in the ASG needs to know anything about the NAT or Elastic IP (EIP), this is handled transparently via the VPC routing tables.

Comment: **Externally-initiated requests** go via the Load Balancer and are routed to the private IP address of an EC2 instance. Responses go back the same way via the Load Balancer. **Internally-initiated requests** go via the NAT Gateway and the Elastic IP address, which also handle responses.